# gnome-software does not show icons of apps

Tags: gnome-software

Installed gnome-software several days ago. the icons of the different programs are not loaded, only placeholders are displayed. screenshots on details page are loaded.

before installing gnome-software I deinstalled the snap-store and snap as presented by this site. https://techwiser.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/

filtered by "gnome software" protocols show these messages.

```
10:54:00 gnome-software: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
10:54:00 gnome-software: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
10:44:15 gnome-software: Only 8 apps for popular list, hiding
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:44:10 gnome-software: hiding category games featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
10:44:10 gnome-software: hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
10:44:10 gnome-software: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache
10:43:51 gnome-software: Failed to reload changed app filter: App filtering is globally disabled
10:43:40 gnome-software: disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, repos, malcontent
10:43:40 gnome-software: enabled plugins: fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, hardcoded-blocklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, odrs, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, packagekit-history, provenance, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons
10:43:40 gnome-software: plugin fwupd took 2,1 seconds to do setup
10:43:38 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=3176 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
```

Comment: Version of Ubuntu? Desktop or Server or Core?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 21.10,  5.13.0-28-generic, @David